# converge/divergence of a series with a n-th root

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

> for the following series, prove for convergence/divergence 
>   $$\sum\limits_{v=1}^\infty   \frac{\sqrt[n]{n}}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}$$

$$\sum\limits_{v=1}^\infty   \frac{\sqrt[n]{n}}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}=\sum\limits_{v=1}^\infty   \sqrt[n]\frac{n}{{n!}}=\sum\limits_{v=1}^\infty   \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{(n-1)!}}$$

now 
$$\sum\limits_{v=1}^\infty   \frac{1}{{n}}=\sum\limits_{v=1}^\infty   \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n^n}}\leq\sum\limits_{v=1}^\infty   \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{(n-1)!}}$$

$\sum\limits_{v=1}^\infty   \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n^n}}$ diverages so by the comparison test $\sum\limits_{v=1}^\infty   \frac{\sqrt[n]{n}}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}$ diverges too.

Is this proof valid?

Comment: Yep you're good. Proof is valid.

Answer (score 2):

Sure.

Comparison test (statement):

Let $(a_n)_n$ and $(b_n)_n$ be two non-negative sequences of real numbers. Suppose that:

$1)$ $\sum_{n\ge1}a_n$ converges.

$2)$ $\exists n_0 \in \mathbb N$, such that $b_n \le a_n$, $\forall n \ge n_0$

Then, $\sum_{n\ge1} b_n$ converges.

Alternative form:

Let $(a_n)_n$ and $(b_n)_n$ be two non-negative sequences of real numbers. Suppose that:

$1)$ $\sum_{n\ge1} b_n$ diverges.

$2)$ $\exists n_0 \in \mathbb N$, such that $b_n \le a_n$, $\forall n \ge n_0$

Then, $\sum_{n\ge1}a_n$ diverges.

Comment: This is just a statement of the comparison tests and does not answer the OP's question: "Is my proof valid?"

Comment: It does. "Sure".

Comment: Perhaps it would be better then if you wrote a sentence: "Your proof is correct."  Otherwise, the "Sure" is vague (and easily passed over/misunderstood--as I clearly did).  The rest is probably not necessary as the OP seems to understand the comparison test quite well.